# Why set a border color with Hex and then rgba?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I see that bootstrap sets border color like this:

```
  border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

Can someone tell me why the rgba follows. What is it doing and don't the rgba zeros override the first line.

Comment: I think the second line is to control the alpha-transparency from the looks of it, instead of setting the actual color. Which is probably why they are all 0s for the RGB values with alpha being the one with actual values.

Comment: The first border color is for older browsers that do not support rgba. If a browser supports rgba, it will override the first rule.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boder-color:#bd362f #bd362f #802420; comination of 3 color values for border. it will look like shadow.

In rgba - Red Green Blue Alpha.  we can add color values(rgb) and opacity value(a).

EXAMPLE : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_rgba